# error warning: Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Tags: r

I have a question about a lm.

if I run this lm it works well.

```
lm(pH58 ~ `rumination (min/d)`, data = phase_data_compleet)
```

however, ph58 is not normally distributed so I have to log transfer the data

```
lm((log(pH58)) ~ `rumination (min/d)`, data = phase_data_compleet)
lm((log(pH58)+1) ~ `rumination (min/d)`, data = phase_data_compleet)
```

however, when I use log transfer the data, the lm does not work anymore.
I get this error all the time:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
> :    NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Can anybody help me with this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably have some pH58 values equal to 0. And log(0) is undefined

Comment: try to do `log(pH58+1)` as the outcome

Comment: Hello mike, thanks for you comment. the code does indeed work when i try log(ph 5.8 +1) however when is use this transformation the data is again not normally distrubed and therefor i do not meet the requirements for linear regression.